LDAP filter. User directory connector. How to retrieve data from a non AD by group
I've been working with Qlik for a long time but this is the first time I have to deal with user directory tasks.
We have stablish correctly the connection with our opendj idm data. By using the LDAP filter
(&(objectClass=person)(cn=usuarioemail)) 

we are able to retrieve the users we need. What we need to achieve is to retrieve the users filtering the group object.
Those are the attributes of both objects
In this case, filter (&(objectClass=person)(cn=usuarioemail)) works fine
Image1
Attribute Description   Value
objectClass inetOrgPerson (structural)
objectClass inetuser (auxiliary)
objectClass organizationalPerson (structural)
objectClass person (structural)
objectClass top (abstract)
objectClass veci-user (structural)
cn  user00447@test0001.org
sn  user00447@test0001.org
inetUserStatus  Active
mail    user00447@test0001.org
samaccountname  user00447@test0001.org
uid user00447@test0001.org

This is the obect we are trying to retrieve users from
image2
Attribute Description   Value
objectClass groupOfNames(structural)
objectClass top (abstract)
cn  ORG-Reporting
member  uid=usuario1@midominio.com,ou=people,dc=partners,dc=[
member  uid=usuario2@midominio.com,ou=people,dc=partners,dc=[
createTimestamp 27 mar 2024 10:10:45 CET (20240327091045Z)
creatorsName    
ds-sync-hist    Binary Data (35 Bytes)
ds-sync-hist    Binary Data (113 Bytes)
ds-sync-hist    Binary Data (113 Bytes)
ds-sync-hist    Binary Data (90 Bytes)
ds-sync-hist    Binary Data (65 Bytes)
entryDN 
entryUUID   
etag    
hasSubordinates false
modifiers Name  cn=Directory Manager,cn=Root DNs,cn=config
modify Timestamp    27 mar 2024 10:11:17 CET (20240327091117Z)
numSubordinates 0
pwdPolicySubentry   cn=Default Password Policy,cn=Password Policies,cn=config
structuralObjectClass   groupOfNames

Using the same connection that worked with users, I've been trying to modify LDAP filter, but I can't retrieve any data.  I.E:
 (&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=ORG-Reporting)) 

Another attempt
(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(member=cn=ORG-Reporting,ou=people,dc=partners,dc=corp))

I've also tried many other combinations of filters but they just don't work. I am wondering if maybe its not possible to retrieve users in this scenario?
I hope I've been clear expressing my porblem, hope you can help me.
Thanks!

What base DN do you have specified next to the filter? Are you trying to retrieve the group entry itself, or are you trying to retrieve user entries for all members of the group?

It seems to me that the object you are trying to retrieve is the group entry itself, but in your example you state the objectClass is inetOrgPerson (whereas the structuralObjectClass operational attribute states groupOfNames). My rough guess is that the base DN for the search is not appropriate for searching groups, that seem to be under the dc=partners node.  But the filter should be (&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=ORG-Reporting))

Hi, my base DN is dc=partners,dc=companyname,dc=corp. Base DN shouldn be a problem cause we are able to retrieve all users by email using the filter:
(&(objectClass=person)(cn=usuarioemail))
Since users can have different domains names, we want the retrieve all members from
objectClass groupOfNames(structural)
objectClass top (abstract)
cn ORG-Reporting

@LudovicPoitou, you are right, i copied the details of my object incorrectly, i edited the post. Sorry about that
